# Creating a New Folder in a Roslyn Project

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a `Project` reference, and I'm adding a new `Document` to that project via `AddDocument()`. The problem is, no matter what I send into the call, the new file always ends up in the root directory of the project. I've tried prepend the `name` of the file with a subdirectory:

```
project.AddDocument(@"\GoHere\MyNewFile.cs", ...)
```

but that doesn't work. Neither does this:

```
project.AddDocument(@"\GoHere\MyNewFile.cs", ..., filePath: @"C:\ProjectPath\GoHere");
```

I've tried other options as well to no avail. Is there some way in the Compiler APIs to add a file to a project in a new subdirectory that doesn't exist? If so, how? TIA.

Comment: I notice there's also a parameter available to define folders -- maybe you could try something out in this area? http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Solution/Project.cs,601

Comment: Yeah, I thought I had tried that and it didn't work, it may have been a combination of things that I was doing wrong along with that approach, but it is the right one..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need to use the optional argument `folders` on [`AddDocument`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Workspace/Solution/Project.cs,f07f0bc37b88156c)

```
SourceText text; 
List<string> folders = new List<string>() { "GoHere" };
project.AddDocument(@"MyNewFile.cs", text, folders: folders);
```

Because you mentioned VS, I just double checked this from `Initialize()` of a VSPackage.

```
var componentModel = (IComponentModel)Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SComponentModel));
var workspace = componentModel.GetService<VisualStudioWorkspace>();

var sourceText = SourceText.From("Test");
var folders = new List<string>() { "GoHere" };
var proj = workspace.CurrentSolution.Projects.Single();
var document = proj.AddDocument("Test.cs", sourceText, folders);

var result = workspace.TryApplyChanges(document.Project.Solution);
```

It appears to add the document properly:

[image]

Comment: Yep, that does the trick. One small addition: don't pass in empty folders to the `folders` property - I got a `COMException` when I did that. But once I made sure I only pass in non-empty folders it worked.

Comment: @JasonBock: if you got a COMException out of Roslyn, please file a bug on https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn. We should do something nicer there.

Answer (score 0):

Get the project's root folder and just create the directory yourself before adding the file. Use `Directory.Create()` and `Path.Combine()` in order to achieve that.

Comment: Unfortunately refactoring projects are by default PCLs, and there's no `Directory.Create()` call that I can use.

Comment: Even if I created the directory before calling `AddDocument()`, the API would still need to add the directory to the project such that it shows up in VS. You can have directories in the directory that the .csproj file is in but they don't by default show up in Solution Explorer.